# Markov Chain (Learning)

Tags: markov-chains, machine-learning

If I have a Matrix like the one below, what is the probability $p_t$ that at a certain time $t$, we are still not able to arrive at state $z$

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text{States} & x & y & \text{$z$} \\
\hline
\text{$x$} & (1-\beta) & \beta & 0 \\
\text{$y$} & (1-\beta) & 0 & \beta \\
\text{$z$} & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
$$

I tried using the law of total probability with the formula,

$\text{Pr}[p_t]=\text{Pr}[p_t|x]\text{Pr}[x]+\text{Pr}[p_t|y]\text{Pr}[y]+\text{Pr}[p_t|z]\text{Pr}[z]$

but I am not sure how to proceed if there is an $\epsilon$ chance of making a mistake.
The way I wrote it is,

$\text{Pr}[p_t]=(1-\epsilon)\beta^{t-1}[(1-\beta)^{t-2}(1-\epsilon)+(1-\beta)^{t-2}(1-\epsilon)+0]$

The first term above is for the probability of staying in state $x$, then for the state $y$ and lastly for the state $z$.

$t=0$ starts at state $x$ and I want to get the probability when the state is in state $y$

Please tell me what to modify to make my question clear.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean that, if we write $w_t$ for the state occupied at time $t$, what is the probability that $w_t \neq z$? $$ \; $$ Also, what is the initial distribution (where does the chain start?)

Comment: I am very sorry for the lack of details...I have updated the question and it seems Aahz's answer is what I am looking for. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint.

Denote $p^x_t$ the probability to not reach $z$ in the next $t$ turns, given that we are now on $x$. Similarly, define $p_t^y$ the probability to not reach $z$ in $t$ turns, given we are now on $y$.

Then you can write the following recursive relation
$$
p_t^x = (1-\beta)p_{t-1}^x + \beta p_{t-1}^y
$$
$$
p_t^y = (1-\beta)p_{t-1}^x
$$

Or combine the two written above to be:

$$
p_t^x = (1-\beta)p_{t-1}^x + \beta (1 - \beta) p_{t-2}^x
$$

This is a recursive formula that should be solved for general $t$. Initial conditions would be $p_1^x = 1, p_2^x = 1 - \beta^2$

Comment: Thank you very much. I believe this is what I was looking for.